# YUI Rich Text Editor: How to set the cursor to the end of the text

Tags: editor, cursor, yui, rte

i want to render a YUI2 Rich Text Editor with some preloaded text. But the cursor is always in the first position of the text. How can i set it at the end of the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using YUI3, but this might still work for YUI2. I'm adding the content with `execCommand('insertandfocus','content')` rather than initializing the editor with the content.

For instance, instead of this:

```
YUI().use('editor', function(Y) {
  var yuiEditor = new Y.EditorBase({
    content: myPreloadedContent
  });
  ...
  yuiEditor.on('frame:ready', function() {
    this.focus();
  });
  ...
});
```

I'm inserting the content like this:

```
YUI().use('editor', function(Y) {
  var yuiEditor = new Y.EditorBase();
  ...
  yuiEditor.on('frame:ready', function() {
    this.focus(function(){
      yuiEditor.execCommand('insertandfocus', myPreloadedContent);
    });
  });
  ...
});
```